# Solr master-master replication alternatives?

Tags: solr, replication, solr4

Currently we have 2 servers with a load-balancer before them. We want to be able to turn 1 machine off and later on, without the user noticing it.
Our application also uses solr and now i wanted to install & configure solr on both servers and the question is how do i configure a master-master replication?

After my initial research i found out that it's not possible :(
But what are my options here? I want both indices to stay in sync and when a document is commited on one server it should also go to the other.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not certain of your specific use case (why turn 1 server on and off?), there is no specific "master-master" replication. Solr does however support distributed indexing and querying via SolrCloud. From the documentation for SolrCloud:

> Replication ensures redundancy for your data, and enables you to send
>   an update request to any node in the shard.  If that node is a
>   replica, it will forward the request to the leader, which then
>   forwards it to all existing replicas, using versioning to make sure
>   every replica has the most up-to-date version.  This architecture
>   enables you to be certain that your data can be recovered in the event
>   of a disaster, even if you are using Near Real Time searching.

It's a bit complex so I'd suggest you spend some time going thru the documentation as it's not quite as simple as setting up a couple of masters and load balancing between them. It is a big step up from the previous master/slave replication that Solr used, so even if it's not a perfect fit it will be a lot closer to what you need.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a simple master - slave replication as described here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication

But be sure you send your inserts, deletes, updates directly to the master, but selects can go through the load balancer.

The other alternative is to create a third server as a master, and 2 slaves, and the lode balancer can be in front of the two slaves.

Comment: Sorry for not writing the essential parts of the description but I think the question was not about how to create the simple replication itself in solr, but how to make a load balanced replication. I think I provided 2 options for the question itself, mentioning the link to the simple replication.